# Замена символов (Регулярные выражения)

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

так как я не силён в регулярных выражениях, прошу здесь помощи.

Нужно заменить все символы `*текст *ещё один текст* текст* на <i>текст <i>ещё один текст</i> текст</i>, а **текст **ещё один текст** текст** на <b>текст <b>ещё один текст</b> текст</b>`

```
то есть * на <i>

а ** на <b>
```

Целый день пытаюсь это реализовать, но ничего не получается. Помогите пожалуйста!

Comment: а закрывающие тэги вам не нужны? и почему регулярные выражения? можно просто пройдя по строе заменить четные вхождения на открывающий, нечетные на закрывающий.

Comment: закрывающие нужны

Comment: @teran, я пытался проходить по строке, но ничего хорошего не вышло, мало опыта у меня

Comment: то есть пробел-звезда-буква на открывающий, буква звезда пробел - закрывающий? так и напишите руглярку

Comment: нет, не так, вот есть `*текст*`, это нужно заменить на `<i>текст</i>`, а если две зведы, то `<b>текст</b>`

Comment: если делать так `/\*(.+?)\*/`, то второе выражение не будет работать, вот это `/\*\*(.+?)\*\*/`

Comment: *Целый день пытаюсь это реализовать, но ничего не получается* - Так поделитесь тем, что вышло, чтобы знать, что именно не получается. Часто бывает так, что задача одна, а делаете вы совсем другое.